# Image not able to show in Google colab using PIL library

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

```
from PIL import Image 
visa_file='/content/visa-logo-mastercard.jpg'
img_visa= Image.open(visa_file,mode='r')
img_visa.show()
```

I am not getting the output of the image in Google colab.

Also the output of **type(img_visa)** is '**PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile**'.

So the image object has been created, but the image is not displaying. And I only want to use PIL to show Image. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just

```
img_visa
```

is enough. You don't need

```
img_visa.show()
```

To be more explicit, you can use

```
display(img_visa)
```